# lookupPrintServices not found network printer on windows

Tags: java, windows, printing, jboss7.x

We are issue with network printer on Windows Server 2008.
Our java application running on JBoss 7.2 is looking for selected printer in available printers:

```
PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
```

everything works fine, but in one moment, PrintService with name of selected printer disappears from the list.
Printing from other applications on that server works fine in same time.

Comment: any exception in log?

Comment: Nothing in the log that was available. Any suggestion what to add for logging?